# How do i redirect the base url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a URL structure of:

```
mysite.com/user/(someusername)
```

and want to redirect only the base URL which is:

```
mysite.com/user/
```

to

```
mysite.com/users/ or mysite.com/members/
```

But the problem is when i add this line to htaccess.

```
redirect 301 /user /users/
```

Even

```
  mysite.com/user/(someusername)
```

gets redirected to

```
mysite.com/users/(someusername)
```

How can i redirect /user/ only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^user/$ users/ [L,R]
```